# vscode - read environment vars on launch

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to debug this issue with vscode - https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop/issues/148#issuecomment-999648216

Not referring to the env vars we can set in workspace's `.vscode/launch.json` or `.vscode/settings.json => "terminal.integrated.env.<platform>"` settings.

Looks like vscode is loading it's own set of env vars from somewhere, and is not reading the `env` I set in `~/.zshrc` (assume it's the same for other terminal startup files as well?).

Anyone aware how to make vscode load up correct env variables on load? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: start VSC from a terminal with the correct environment vars set, if you launch it from the desktop/taskbar it does not start from a terminal so some unknown environment is used

Comment: Thank you @rioV8  that helped. Launching the code (sub-process) from terminal (main-process) will make it inherit all it's settings, forgot the basics 